# flv player control time

Tags: apache-flex, video, flv, keyframe

I am using the flex flv player component and i want to be able to skip 5 seconds forward and backwards , at the moment from what i understand from the documents it is not acurate because the movie can only skip to keyframes sometimes making the skip 6 or 7 seconds. the same goes to cue points which the flv might miss the actual point if there is no keyframe there/
my question is there any other way to use the player in a more accurate manner ? since i see on the web players that can do these skipps

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

The ability to seek into an FLV file is entirely dependent upon the key frame spacing.  That is because a key frame can create an entire video image all by itself.  (As opposed to intra-frames, which are dependent upon *a)* the *previous* key frame, and *b)* all inter-frames between it and the previous key frame.)  That's just they way it works.

But maybe you have some influence over how the videos are encoded?  Could you specify a minimum key frame spacing?  E.g.: A key frame spacing of 50 for a 25fps video would be every 2s.  Or even smaller?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed such a player, you can use flv-player.net, and copy js player. there is no control bar, so you can then control all the feature from javascript,

download flv-player.js.swf along with demo code, write your own control bar, mean play , seek , pause , volume , and fullscreen.

So you will need extra effort to write these feature becuase the player that i mention have not any control bar.